# AngularJS define component's controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular version 1.5.8.

Here is simplified code of my HTML page:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="identicaApp">
        <div id="navbar_wrapper">
            <navbar-component></navbar-component>
        </div>
        <div id="register_player_wrapper">
            <register-player></register-player>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/static/angular/identica/identica.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/angular/identica/common.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/angular/identica/navbar/navbar.module.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/angular/identica/navbar/navbar.component.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/angular/identica/registration/register_player/register-player.module.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/angular/identica/registration/register_player/register-player.component.js"></script>
</body>
```

Navbar is loading correctly, but register-player component is not loading at all, without any errors. Here is code of register-player.component.js:

```
angular.module('identicaApp.registration.player', ['identicaApp.common'])
    .component('registerPlayer', {
        templateUrl: '/static/angular/identica/registration/register_player/register_player.html',
        controller: ['$resource', '$http', 'geolocationProvider', function RegisterPlayerController($resource, $http, geolocationProvider) {
            // logic here
        }]
    });
```

I've tried to define controller inside

```
<div id="navbar_wrapper" ng-controller="RegisterPlayerController">
```

or

```
<navbar-component ng-controller="RegisterPlayerController"></navbar-component>
```

but in this case angular falls with error `Argument 'RegisterPlayerController' is not a function, got undefined`. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Why are you trying to add `component's` controller via `ng-controller`? I mean what for? Why do you need to add it somwhere outside at all?

Comment: @Kindzoku just trying to do something to make it work

Comment: Use `controllerAs` and inside `register_player.html` just use it

Comment: Component doesn't require `controllerAs`. It's already have `$ctrl` alias

Comment: Try to remove all injections and simplify your register_player.html, just to make sure it works at all, because all seems ok in your example, except ng-controllers.

Comment: @Kindzoku It works when I load it as a separate application through `ng-app`

Comment: Do you have the module dependency on `identicaApp`?

Comment: Can you post whole component code pls. Maybe you simplified the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the case that module 'identicaApp.registration.player' is not inlcuded in your main controller as a input.
For Exmaple.
angular.module('identicaApp', ['identicaApp.registration.player'])

Try this and refresh your page , it should work fine.

Comment: that's it, I could not understand why I should declare that bigger module depends on smaller

Comment: Base module name is "identicaApp"  (as shown in above code ng-app="identicalApp")

Now , if we want to use any other module (however large it may be) in our base application. 
Then , we need to inject that in our base module, otherwise it will not identify any of its 
components.
For Example : Here RegisterPlayerController got undefined . RegisterPlayerController is 
defined inside moduel 'identicaApp.registration.player'

Point is that just injecting the controller name is not sufficient , we need to inject its
module in our base module.